# How to check whether same gender is selected or not using checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have checkboxes inside "td" tag of table like

```
     <td>    
    <input gender="Female" id="5c6434a8590a0654a0002b5a" academicyearid="5b879ec6590a062ba4005fdb" type="checkbox">
    </td>  
      
    <td>    
    <input gender="Female" id="5c6434a8590a0654a0002b0a" academicyearid="5b879ec6590a062ba4005fdb" type="checkbox">
    </td>    

     <td>    
    <input gender="Male" id="5c6434a8590a0654a0002b04" academicyearid="5b879ec6590a062ba4005fdb" type="checkbox">
    </td>
```

In jQuery, I am tweaking below lines of code like

```
    function onSubmit()
    {  
        $('.commoncheckbox input:checked').each(function () {
                
          var gender = $(this).attr('gender');    
          alert("only students of one gender can be selected"); 
         });
    }
```

Basically, I want when user will click submit button and onSubmit button event it will check which checkboxes are checked and if their gender is different, then it should show alert message saying that "only students of one gender can be selected".

Comment: First of all, the jquery code will never be triggered because there is no class with the  name commoncheckbox

Comment: `othergender ?`

Comment: it is just dummy code

Comment: Attach a change event to the checkboxes and when that gets triggered, get the gender attr of other checked checkboxes, if it contains a different gender, then pop up the alert

Comment: What exactly you want to do? selection of only male OR female?

Comment: Why is gender tied to selecting courses? Can't you just like, show only the classes available to the gender they selected before in a different part of the form? That would be a more pleasant experience than being able to click things that you aren't supposed to be able to click.

Comment: what will be the value of other gender ,is it a male or female

Comment: i have updated my question

Comment: I want when user will click submit button and onSubmit button event it will check which checkboxes are checked and if their gender is different, then it should show alert messsage saying that "only students of one gender can be selected"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a single if can do what you want based on good selectors

```
// if there is both male & female checkboxes checked
if ($('input[gender="Male"]:checked').length && $('input[gender="Female"]:checked').length) {

// display alert message

}
```

Or am I making a mistake understanding your problem ?

Comment: Problem : `$('input[gender="Male"]:checked')` will always be truthy, because it returns a jQuery object. Test for the length instead : `$('input[gender="Male"]:checked').length` and then get an upvote :)

Comment: I edited and learned a thing, I thought it will returned undefined then, thanks :)

Comment: I want when user will click submit button and onSubmit button event it will check which checkboxes are checked and if their gender is different, then it should show alert messsage saying that "only students of one gender can be selected"

Comment: @Nida that's exactly what this code does. Best answer here

Comment: @Nida just integrate this into your onSubmit function

Answer (score 2):

```js
function validateGender(){
  const uniqGenderSet = new Set();
  $('table input:checked').each(function () {
        uniqGenderSet.add($(this).attr('gender'));
  });
  if (uniqGenderSet.size > 1) 
        alert("only students of one gender can be selected");
}

$('button').click(function() {
  validateGender();
});
```

```css
input[gender="Female"]{
  outline: 1px solid pink;
}
input[gender="Male"]{
  outline: 1px solid skyblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<td>    
    <input gender="Female" id="5c6434a8590a0654a0002b5a" academicyearid="5b879ec6590a062ba4005fdb" type="checkbox">
    </td>  

    <td>    
    <input gender="Female" id="5c6434a8590a0654a0002b0a" academicyearid="5b879ec6590a062ba4005fdb" type="checkbox">
    </td>    

     <td>    
    <input gender="Male" id="5c6434a8590a0654a0002b04" academicyearid="5b879ec6590a062ba4005fdb" type="checkbox">
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<button>Vaidate</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use const for othergender and give it a predefined gender

```js
var gender;
var othergender;
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.a').change(function(){

othergender=$(this).val()
$('.a').prop("disabled",true)
})
  $('.b').change(function(){
         
          gender=$(this).attr('gender');
          console.log(gender)
          if(gender != othergender)// just an idea  
          {
          alert("only students of one gender can be selected"); 
          $(this). prop("checked", false);
          $('.a').prop("disabled",false)
          $('.a').prop("checked", false);
          othergender='';
          }

  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td>   
<input class="a" type="checkbox" value="Male"/>Male

<input class="a" type="checkbox" value="Female"/>Female
<br>
    <input class="b" gender="Female" id="5c6434a8590a0654a0002b5a" academicyearid="5b879ec6590a062ba4005fdb" type="checkbox">
    </td>  

    <td>    
    <input class="b" gender="Female" id="5c6434a8590a0654a0002b0a" academicyearid="5b879ec6590a062ba4005fdb" type="checkbox">
    </td>    

     <td>    
    <input class="b" gender="Male" id="5c6434a8590a0654a0002b04" academicyearid="5b879ec6590a062ba4005fdb" type="checkbox">
    </td>
```

Comment: Run the snippet, only check Male, you get the rejection alert and you can't check it.

Comment: because the variable is already set to female, if set to male it will select male only

Comment: ...but I can't select male. Finding why the code doesn't work won't make it work :)

Comment: Just did. I checked male, then I checked female without problem (which is wrong). Then I checked the third and fourth box (?) without problem. Then the last one gave me an alert. I don't really get the logic of this :)

Comment: The first 2 checkboxes are to select which gender you want. You can select both. The latter 3 are where the logic applies. If male is selected and then you try to select from the other 3 you will get the result

Comment: Ah, I get it, nice idea. However I ended up with "Female" selected (meaning I should only be able to select female checkboxes) and then below, I could select all three checkboxes from both genders, without problem :/

Comment: Now it works, but I can't change my mind :) As soon as I check "Male" then both top checkboxes get disabled... So what if I change my mind and I want to select only females now? I can't

Comment: Hahaha now I could select both male AND female and get both disabled XD Ok just use radio buttons for the top ones, stop using checkboxes, it'll make your life way easier

Answer (score 1):

If you can access the user gender, why not use jquery to add the attribute checked using `.prop('checked', true);`

```js
var gender='male';
if(gender=='male'){

  $('#input').prop( "checked" );
}
```

```html
<html>
<head><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script></head>
<body>
<input type='checkbox' id='check' checked='false'>
<label for="check">Check me</label>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The answer is completely different to the above question

Comment: @Deepak he wants to check the input on the submit, but he can check the correct input and 'select' it, and add disable to all inputs to avoid have to check that parameters in the submit

Comment: `var gender='male'; if(gender=='male')` ?? What kind of condition is that? :) And indeed, the answer has nothing to do with the initial problem

Comment: @JeremyThille just an example, i dont know  poster's  implementation

Comment: Well, the question is clear. You have three checkboxes, two females, one male; you can't select two checkboxes of different genders. Now how does your answer solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
var selectedGender;
$('.commoncheckbox input:checked').each(function () {
    var gender = $(this).attr('gender');
    if(selectedGender & selectedGender !== gender) {
       alert("only students of one gender can be selected");
    }
    selectedGender = gender;
});
```